# apply fabric image filter tint

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to apply image color using fabric.js tint. I found an [example](http://fabricjs.com/image-filters/), which I tried to apply with no luck:

```
var active = canvas.getActiveObject();
if (active && active.type === 'image') {
    var color = $(this).css("background-color");
    var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.Tint({
        color : '#3513B0',
        opacity : 0.5
    });
    active.filters.push(filter);
    active.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
}
else{
    active.set('fill',color);   
}
```

Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmoq0jtf/4/).